# Proof that a scaling factor of $a$ scales a polygon's area by $a^2$?

Tags: geometry, area

I need to find and prove the scaling of a polygon's area when you scale it by a factor of $a$. I've searched for a long while, and I've found answers saying that it's $a^2$, but there is no proof for it.
All I've found so far is a mention of this saying that it's hard to prove, or visual interpretations using a rectangle/triangle, but no general $n$-gon.
I have no clue where to start since there is not a general formula for the area of any $n$-gon. Could anyone help me out?

Comment: You can divide the polygon into triangles. Each triangle will have sides scaled up by $a$. Now use heron's formula to conclude that each triangle's area is scaled up by $a^2$.

Comment: One hint: you can break any polygon into triangles and solve that way. Another is that there's an explicit formula for the area of a polygon in terms of cross products between adjacent edges and you can check that every individual term in this formula is quadratic in the coordinates, so the quadratic scaling factor comes naturally.

Comment: I need a general proof for any n-gon though, how could I separate them into triangles, then?

Comment: You can split any polygon with more than three edges into polygons with fewer edges and continue doing so until you have triangles

Comment: @Ji-HaRajesh: *"how could I separate them into triangles, then?"* See, for instance, Wikipedia's  ["Triangulation" entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon_triangulation).

Comment: An overkill approach is to invoke the [Wallace-Bolyai-Gerwein Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallace–Bolyai–Gerwien_theorem): *Any two polygons with the same area are "equidecomposable";* ie, you can *dissect* one polygon into finitely-many pieces that can be re-arranged to form the other polygon. In particular, a given polygon is equidecomposable with a square of the same area. Thus, if you believe the area-scales-by-$a^2$ property for squares, then the WBG Theorem transfers that property to polygons. As I wrote: *overkill*. Still, WBG is an interesting result to know.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how to prove that the triangles' sides are doubled, right now. As for the Wallace-Bolyai-Gerwein Theorem, I really don't know how to apply it.

Comment: What is your understanding of the meaning of scaling a polygon by a factor of $a$? If you want a very fundamental proof without appeal to "obvious" facts then you need careful, precise definitions of the things you are talking about.

Comment: I guess it's multiplying each side of the n-gon by *a*.

Comment: It has to be more specific than that. The area of a polygon of more than three sides is not determined by the lengths of its sides. So if all you do is make a polygon with sides $a$ times as long, **it is not necessarily true** that the area is $a^2$ times as great.

Comment: I think what you're missing is that the angles at corresponding vertices in the original polygon and the scaled polygon are congruent. From this you can start making deductions about how to split the polygon into triangles. Of course that requires you first to have proved that you can always do that, which is a significant amount of work. But if you want to prove something *for every polygon* while using only simple geometry (no linear algebra, no general formulas in coordinate geometry, etc.) then you have a lot to prove.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the transformation $h_a: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ given by "multiplication by" $a$. Then, any figure $X\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ of area $A$ gets transformed into a figure $h_a(X)$ of area $a^2 A$.

To see this, just apply the "change of variables" theorem to the integral calculating the area of $X$. The jacobian here is $\det(h_a) = a^2$.

This proves that any plane figure's area is scaled by $a^2$, not just polygons.

Comment: This is of course correct, but I think that arguing this way is very much putting the cart before the horse.

Comment: Is there a non-linear algebra way to prove this?

Comment: I don't understand. Area is a bilinear form on the two directions of the plane, a multilinear algebra concept. The determinant gives the scaling factor of rectangles, and every figure can be arbitrarily approximated by rectangles. It completely explains why the result is true.